# Textbook claims can use age=age instead of this.age = age in ctor, when is this correct?

Tags: java

For this class,

```
class Person {
    int age;
    public Person(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

In my textbook, the author tells me that it's also OK to write age=age to replace this.age=age.

He says, if the parameter and the data member have the same name, the left side of the assignment symbol will be treated as the data member of the class, and the right side is the parameter.

I have jdk1.7 installed on my computer, and codes like age=age has no effect. In which version of Java does that work?

Comment: when that doesn't work on the latest version of `jdk`, why do you wanna go back to some old version of `jdk`?

Comment: ... especially as that has to be a _very_ old one (if there is one, as I can't recall any. Going back to 1.2, I don't remember such constructs working...) Why do you use that old book? You can even find good quality free tutorials and learning material on the internet these days...

Comment: I don't know which version, but you don't want it. Just go with `this.age = age`. Better all around.

Comment: I actually don't ever recall this working, but even if it did, I would have never written it like that. Ugh.

Comment: Dear downvoters, this is actually a very good question.  OP saw it in a (shitty, shitty) textbook and took the effort of asking if it was version-dependent.  What are you going to say?  Go read a book before posting here?

Comment: Though I don't think downvoting this question is warranted. The OP is trying to find clarification of something (erroneous) found in a textbook.

Comment: @miaowhehe As Stephen C suggested, please post the title of the book...

Comment: Agreed, this is a legitimate question.

Comment: Oh my god.......The textbook's name is Object-Oriented Program Design-Java(Second Edition). I'm a Chinese student and this is my college textbook. I think this book has no English version. Ah.........>_<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen this. At least Im sure Java 1.4 works the same as 1.7 in this respect.

Just stick to using:

```
this.age = age;
```

Perhaps the textbook refers to this case, as this will work. As there is no local variable `age` it will assign `customAge` to the class field `age`:

```
class Person {
    int age;
    public Person(int customAge) {
        age = customAge;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably time to use a different book :)

Comment: @miaowhehe [Core Java](http://www.amazon.com/Core-Java-Volume-I-Fundamentals-Edition/dp/0132354764) is standard.  [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683) is an intermediate-to-advanced textbook that you will benefit from reading sooner than later.

Answer (score 4):

The book is dead wrong and should be replaced.  Use a different book.  `age = age` will never have any effect and hopefully produce a compiler warning.

Comment: Thanks, sir. I've found many other errors in this book and can't trust it at all.

Answer (score 4):

> He says, if the parameter and the data member have the same name, the left side of the assignment symbol will be treated as the data member of the class, and the right side is the parameter.

This is not valid in any version of Java released by Sun / Oracle, or any language that conforms to any release of the Java Language Specification.

Please provide the name and author of the book where you found this claim.

Comment: Nor in any language I've ever heard of.

Comment: That too ... but I wouldn't discount that there is *some* language that works that way.

Comment: @DaveNewton - but there are tricky languages around.  Indeed quite a few languages have tricky features.  (Algol60 call by name, FORTRAN assigned goto, old-style COBOL which didn't have proper procedures, C / C++ which both have a myriad of "undefined" behaviours, etc)

Comment: I used javac -source from 1.2 to 1.7, and none of them works. That's my college textbook called Object-Oriented Program Design-Java(Second Edition). Maybe it has only a Chinese version.